# Insert objects without matching column name

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

This is probably a silly question, but I am new to node and postgresql, so I am struggling.

I am trying to use `pgp.helpers.insert` to insert multiple objects into the database, as the example bellow:

```js
users = [{mycolumn:{name: 'John', age:23}}, {mycolumn:{name: 'Mike', age: 30}}];
query = pgp.helpers.insert(users, ['mycolumn:json'], 'mytable');
// insert into "mytable"("mycolumn") values('{"name":"John","age":23}'),('{"name":"Mike","age":30}')
```

The code above inserts into `mytable` 2 rows with `mycolumn` as a jsonb.

But I am trying to insert straight into `mycolumn` the values inside an array of objects, without wrapping my original object, such as:

```js
users = [{name: 'John', age:23}, {name: 'Mike', age: 30}];
query = pgp.helpers.insert(users, ['mycolumn:json'], 'mytable');
// Error: Property 'mycolumn' doesn't exist.
```

Of course it doesn't work, since the object doesn't contain a `mycolumn` attribute. But I think it is not elegant to iterate in my array wrapping the original object with the column name, specially since I am working with millions of rows (working in batches, of course).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following definition for your column, as per the [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html) syntax:

```
{
  name: 'mycolumn',
  init: c => c.source // use the source object itself
}
```

i.e.

```
const cs = new pgp.helpers.ColumnSet([
    {
      name: 'mycolumn',
      init: c => c.source
    }
], {table: 'mytable'});
```

and then use it:

```
const query = pgp.helpers.insert(users, cs);
```

Note that we are not specifying the modifier - `mod: ':json'`, because we are returning an object from `init`, and objects are formatted as JSON by default.